# does replica shard has translog files

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Elasticsearch maintain translog files for each shard , does replica shard has translog files ?

```
{
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 2,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "_all" : {
    "primaries" : {
      "translog" : {
        "operations" : 0,
        "size_in_bytes" : 55,
        "uncommitted_operations" : 0,
        "uncommitted_size_in_bytes" : 55,
        "earliest_last_modified_age" : 3625527568
      }
    },
    "total" : {
      "translog" : {
        "operations" : 0,
        "size_in_bytes" : 110,
        "uncommitted_operations" : 0,
        "uncommitted_size_in_bytes" : 110,
        "earliest_last_modified_age" : 3625520206
      }
    }
  },
 
    }
  }
}
```

I can't see replica detail in above query result.
Elasticsearch version 7.16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Elasticsearch maintain `translog` for all shards including replica as well, and `total` is showing information of all shards, you can notice its double in your query response.

My Guess is that you have  1 replica configured .

Also, read the snippet from [official Elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-translog.html#_translog_settings), that mention that translog are updated for all allocated replicas.

[image]

Comment: "_all" : {
    "primaries" : {
      "translog" : {
        "operations" : 124900,
        "size_in_bytes" : 125203232,
        "uncommitted_operations" : 124900,
        "uncommitted_size_in_bytes" : 125203232,
        "earliest_last_modified_age" : 328024
      }
    },
    "total" : {
      "translog" : {
        "operations" : 605032,
        "size_in_bytes" : 605110040,
        "uncommitted_operations" : 605032,
        "uncommitted_size_in_bytes" : 605110040,
        "earliest_last_modified_age" : 328024
      }
    }
  },

Comment: what is double are you talking about translog operation if we add primary translog operation two times it is equal to total translog operation.I was understanding that my query should also displayed replica translog just as primary

Comment: @aniketpant to test this, you create a sample index with 1 primary shards and 1 replica shards, and check the same API without indexing any doc, it should show `operations` under translog for both primary and total as 0, now index one document and check the response, you will see 1 under primary and 2 under total, hope this makes it clear

Comment: Ok i will check